# LINQ. Return Matching Records from second table.

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am new to LINQ. I have the following three database tables .

```
class Districts{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public String DistrictName{get;set;}
}

class Users{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public String Username{get;set;}
 //etc
}
```

And a Join Table

```
class UserDistricts{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public int Userid{get;set;}
 public int DistrictId{get;set;}
}
```

I want to find the DistrictNames assigned to a particular User identified by its UserId.

```
List<int> districtsAssigned = (from aDistrict in p.UserDistricts where 
aDistrict.UserId == userId select aDistrict.DistrictId).ToList();
```

The above code gives me the DistrictId for a particular User. I want it to match with the District Tables and return me the District Name. I am stuck here.

The equivalent SQL Query would be like this.

```
select U.DistrictId,D.DistrictName,userId from UserDistricts U 
INNER JOIN Districts D on D.DistrictId=U.DistrictId 
where userId=@UID
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a try with SO Linq documentation for [Joins](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2994/joins-inner-left-right-cross-and-full-outer-joins#t=201704050730121811661)

Comment: why do you have this table? UserDistricts? is it a many-to-many relation with Districts and Users? if so you dont need  `public int id{get;set;}` within the UserDistricts, only leftkey and rightkey

Comment: also tell me Are you using LINQ to SQL? or Entity framework/LINQ2Entities?

Comment: It is a many-to-many relationship

Comment: You can use `join` as @GiladGreen suggested (almost direct one to one SQL query translation), but don't you have navigation properties? Because with navigation properties the query will be straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `join` in LINQ, too:

```
from userDistrict in p.UserDistricts
join district in p.Districts on userDistrict.DistrictId equals district.id
where userDistrict.UserId == userId
select district.DistrictName
```

A join is not used very often in LINQ, since there are other, more flexible options. In this case this would be:

```
from userDistrict in p.UserDistricts
from district in p.Districts
where (userDistrict.DistrictId == district.id) && (userDistrict.UserId == userId)
select district.DistrictName
```

This allows for complex join conditions, while `join` only allows comparison for equality.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier using syntax-based query:

```
var entryPoint = (from U in Users
                 join ud in UserDistricts on U.UserID equal ud.UserID
                 join d in Districts on d.DistrictID equals ud.DistrictID
                 where ud.UserID == U.UserID
                 select new {
                    DistrictId = ud.DistrictId,
                    DistrictName= d.DistrictName,
                    UserID=  U.UserID
                 }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Virtual relationship between classes and we can achive it easily with the help of Navigation properties

```
class UserDistricts{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public Users Userid{get;set;}
 public Districts DistrictId{get;set;}
}
```

then create a ViewModel like

```
class DistrictDetails{
     public int userId {get;set;}
     public string DistrictName{get;set;}
     public int DistrictId{get;set;}
}
```

After that you can add this type to the list as follows

```
List<DistrictDetails> districtsAssigned = _context.UserDistricts
    .Where(x=>x.Userid == userId) 
    .Select(y=> new DistrictDetails 
         {
            DistrictId==y.Districts.DistrictId,
            DistrictName=y.Districts.DistrictName,
            userId == y.d
         }).ToList();
```